# Is it good practice to use a VM for Django projects?

Tags: django, virtual-machine, virtualenv

So I was looking at the Getting Started with Django http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/ tutorial, and everything was done in a vm. The author set up a vm, and then created a virtualenv in the vm. Is this good practice to get started on a django project, or software projects in general? Why the need for a vm? What happens if I have more than one project - should I use two vms? Or just create additional virtualenvs in the original vm?

I'm still a student in school, and I'm working on my own personal side projects, so it'd be useful to get some input on how things are really done in the real world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not **need** VMs. You can get through just fine using virtualenv with an environment for each project - especially just starting out in Django.

In the future, one of the times you may need a separate VM environment for your project is if it has a lot of unique infrastructure needs. It's much easier to setup a VM, setup the unique environment, and not have to alter it when you want to work on other projects.

Another common reason I see people using VMs is when they have a Windows machine but want to develop in Linux. It's easy to spin up a Linux VM and work there since Linux is more programmer friendly.

Comment: Assuming I don't use VMs, if I make a second project, should it be in a new virtualenv then? Also, if I eventually want to deploy my project to heroku (I know they use ubuntu), would it make sense to use a VM since I have a windows machine?

Comment: Yes it should be in a new virtualenv. Let me clarify, this is not required, but it is a very very good practice to get in the habit of using. And you can deploy to Heroku straight from the virtualenv even on Windows. You will have no issues there. Check out Getting Started with Heroku for Django: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Answer (score 1):

It's subjective. I leverage virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper for my development, which I do on Linux. There are instance where you might need to leverage two separate VMs...it just depends, although I haven't encountered this.

There's no unwritten rule that says you have to use a VM. Python (and many other languages/frameworks) simply work better on Linux, so many people will leverage VMs to run Linux on Windows or Mac to do their development in that environment.